# Connecting a BU-353-S4

Tags: usb, gps

This is very much like the question at "[How to use gps receiver bu-353](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30569/how-to-use-gps-receiver-bu-353)" except that answer didn't get me all the way there.

I am trying to connect a BU-353-S4 by GLOBAL-SAT for use with OpenCPN.
**I can get the receiver to work in gpsmon**, not in xgps, cgps or OpenCpn.
 Does anyone know how to get it to work in openCPN?

**Output of: ls**

```
ls /dev/ttyUSB
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

**Output of: gpsd -n -N -D 2 /dev/ttyUSB0**

```
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv4 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv6 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
```

This is **after** I removed and reinstalled gpsd & gpsd-clients, but before I re-started gpsd.

Answer (score 2):

This cured my problem:

I stumbled on to another forum that said to try changine the default settings for gpsd at [**/etc/default/gpsd**] to this.

```
# Default settings for the gpsd init script and the hotplug wrapper.
```

## Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time

START_DAEMON="false"

## Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon

USBAUTO="true"

## Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.

## They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.

DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"

## Other options you want to pass to gpsd

GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G -b"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"

## end of file gpsd

to my surprise it worked.